# ID not getting displayed from JSON data

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am getting data from a json file and displaying it on a site. For some reason it does not display the ID. Please guide.

```
function getJSON() {
    /** These are the lyrics to Hello Dolly */
$slices = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://pf.tradetracker.net/?aid=1&type=json&encoding=utf8&fid=251713&categoryType=2&additionalType=2&limit=1000',true));
if ($slices) { 
   foreach ($slices as $slice) {
      $ID = $slice->products->ID;
      echo $ID;
  }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root element is products, so use:

```
foreach ($slices->products as $slice) {
      $ID = $slice->ID;
      echo $ID;
  }
```